# Load data from a remote URL not working with BT5

Tags: json, bootstrap-table, bootstrap-5

I am trying to load data from a remote URL by setting `data-url=""`. Everything works with Bootstrap v4, but when I use the last version of Bootstrap (v5.0.1), the data is not loaded.

I tried different options: only Bootstrap Bundle with Popper, jQuery + Bootstrap Bundle with Popper or separate scripts solution but nothing seems to work.

```
<table 
    id="table" 
    data-toggle="table" 
    data-url="http://satico.beget.tech/json/google-apps-script.json" 
    >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Parent ID</th>
            <th data-field="title">Parent Title</th>
            <th data-field="children[*].guid">Guids</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

My testing page http://satico.beget.tech/lib-bootstrap-table.html

My data http://satico.beget.tech/json/google-apps-script.json

A getting started of add Bootstrap Table to Bootstrap v5 https://bootstrap-table.com/themes/bootstrap5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the data from http://satico.beget.tech/json/google-apps-script.json is returing a single object instead of an array. Bootstrap Table requires the data from `data-url` to be a JSON array.

[Working demo](https://codeply.com/p/xv76DA20nE)